# 404 Error when using Http Interceptor in Angula/Ionic 4

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, http-status-code-404, interceptor

This link is for a tutorial on using an interceptor for mock api calls in Angular/Ionic 4.

https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-make-http-calls-and-handle-responses-easily-using-an-interceptor/

I've tried following a few tutorials like this one and they all end in a 404 blaming the url which for me was: http://localhost:8100/api/getdetails

My question is how can I make this tutorial work, or what is wrong with the tutorial or technique? I would really like to implement a mock API. If you know a DIFFERENT way of creating a mock API that might also be a solution to my problem.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: there are so many videos on Youtube for HTTP-INTERCEPTIOR, you should watch some other tutorial: https://youtu.be/IJWCpa_-MeU

Comment: While I thank you for your offering, I have actually read through other tutorials doing what I am trying to do and I always get the 404. I chose a simple tut that perfectly shows my issue. It is using the same angular and ionic major versions. When I create a new project and copy the code from the tut I get an 404error. I am certain it wasn't like that when he wrote the tut.

Comment: 90% in this case error is on server side. Please check with postman if everything on your server is working